# file_get_contents(): SSL context creation failure in Apache2 but works in CLI

Tags: php, apache, ssl, openssl, file-get-contents

Since this morning, we have lots of errors on many sites hosted on our server :

```
file_get_contents(): SSL context creation failure
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
```

This happens on various environments (Wordpress, Symfony EWZRecaptcha ...) so I have isolated the problem in a single php file :

`<?php echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com"); ?>`

When that file is called through Apache, it fails with same error messages !
But when called through CLI, it works well !

So, I tried copying Apache php.ini over CLI php.ini, but it still works through CLI !

I can't find where these errors come from...

What I tried :

- Restart Apache / PHP
- Updated OpenSSL
- Checked the time of the server
- Updated the cacert from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Any help ?

Comment: Is your Apache server using the same php instalation invoked from CLI ? have you tried using other alternatives like `Curl` ?

Comment: Yes, same php installation invoked from CLI and Apache. Yes Curl works in Apache and CLI

Comment: @PsY4 Did you ever get this resolved for `file_get_contents`?